# Jquery code not working when modal is called with href in order to pass Get values

Tags: jquery

i'm developing a site and on my site there are functionalities where a modal containing a dynamically populated form, is called up in order to carry out database updates.

For me to be able to pass get values to my modal, so that i can be able to dynamically fill up the form inputs with database values, first of all, i declare the modal on the launch page and use href to call up it's remaining contents. I'll make some sample codes below:

customer.php

```
    <html>
    <header>
    </header>

    <body>

    <div class="modal fade" data-keyboard="false"  id="customer_updateModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="customer_updateModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
<div class="modal-content">
                                                                                </div>
        </div>
        </div>

    <a data-toggle='modal' data-target='#customer_updateModal' href='modals/customer_updateModal.php?id=<?php echo $staff['customer_key'];?>' role='button'></a>

    </body>

    </html>
```

customer_updateModal.php

```
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>

</div>

<div class="modal-body">
                                                                                        <div class="database">

<form method="post">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="cn">Customer Name</label>
<input type="text"name="name" value='<?php echo $this->get_customer;?>'>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="em">Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email" value='<?php echo $this->get_customerEmail; ?>'>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="pr">Product</label>
<input type="text" name="address" value='<?php echo $this->get_customerAddress; ?>'>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="pn">Phone</label>
<input type="text" name="phone" value='<?php echo $this->get_customerPhone; ?>'>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
                                                                                            </div>
                                                                                    </div>

<div class="modal-footer">                                                                                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

I encounter a problem when submitting my modal form because i use jquery to make submission to avoid a page reload. I've tried including a jquery lib to my customer_updateModal.php page, but it causes problems to my web sites functionalities when the modal opens, even though the jquery code begins to work. I've also tried putting my jquery code on the launch page(customer.php) and this didn't work either. I'd be happy if i can find a good way to handle this because i'm very new to jquery so i don't know how and also why i'm encountering this problem.

Comment: `it causes problems to my web sites functionalities` how? what specific errors/problems are you getting?

Comment: i use bootstrap, though i didn't code the front end, but the nav menu drop's down when u hover the mouse over it, to show the page links, but this stops working.